# Javascript- JQuery tr.addClass('shown') not woking

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, datatable

I Have the following table:

```
<table class="table align-middle table-row-dashed fs-6 gy-5 row-child">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-start text-gray-400 fw-bolder fs-7 text-uppercase gs-0">
      <th class="min-w-125px">
        header1
      </th>
      <th class="min-w-125px">
        header2
      </th>
      <th class="min-w-125px">
        header3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="bodyTableReport">
    //body is generated via Ajax
  </tbody>
</table>
```

That is filled with the following function:

```
function LoadTable(data) {
  ClearTableBodyHTML();
  data.forEach(d => {
    const {
      prop1,
      prop2,
      prop3,
      child1,
      child2
    } = d;
    var date = document.querySelector('#kt_datepicker_1').value;
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    var rowChild = {
      child1: child1,
      child2: child2
    };
    arraysubTable[body1] = rowChild;
    row.innerHTML = `<td>${body1}</td>
                    <td>${body2}</td>
                    <td>${body3}</td>`;
    document.querySelector('#bodyTableReport').appendChild(row);
  })
}
```

The problem is that I have a sub-table for each row with more data and a button to show it with this function:

```
$('#bodyTableReport').on('click', '.button-subtable', function() {
  console.log("entered");
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var idservice = $(this).closest('.button-subtable').attr('idservice');
  var row;
  if ($(this).hasClass('all-services')) {
    row = tableAllService.row(tr);
  } else {
    row = table.row(tr);
  }

  table.row

  if (row.child.isShown()) {
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
  } else {
    row.child(format(idservice)).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});
```

And the format method is to prepare the sub-table:

```
function format(d) {
  var employees;
  var vehicle;

  if (arraysubTable[d] != null) {
    employees = arraysubTable[d].Employees.map(function(emp) {
      return `<div class="employee-list">
                 <div class="employee-item" >
                  <p> 
                    <strong>Apellido: </strong> ${emp.lastName} <br> 
                    <strong>Nombre: </strong> ${emp.name}  <br> 
                    <strong>Tipo de Empleado: </strong> ${emp.typeEmployee} 
                  </p>
                  </div>
                    </div>`
    });
    vehicle = `<p> 
                <strong>IdInterno: </strong> ${arraysubTable[d].InternID} <br> 
                <strong>Distrito: </strong> ${arraysubTable[d].District}  <br> 
                <strong>Dominio: </strong> ${arraysubTable[d].Plate} 
              </p>`
  } else {
    employees = arraysubTableAll[d].Employees.map(function(emp) {
      return `<div class="employee-list">
                  <div class="employee-item" >
                    <p> 
                      <strong>Apellido: </strong> ${emp.lastName} <br> 
                      <strong>Nombre: </strong> ${emp.name}  <br> 
                      <strong>Tipo de Empleado: </strong> ${emp.typeEmployee}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                    </div>`
    });
    vehicle = `<p> 
                <strong>IdInterno: </strong> ${arraysubTableAll[d].InternID} <br> 
                <strong>Distrito: </strong> ${arraysubTableAll[d].District}  <br> 
                <strong>Dominio: </strong> ${arraysubTableAll[d].Plate} 
              </p>`
  }


  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  return `
        <div class="service-child" >
            <div class="vehicle-child" >
                <strong class="text-black">Vehiculo</strong>
                ${vehicle}
            </div>
            <div class="employees-child">
                <strong class="text-black">Empleados</strong>
                <div class="item-employee">
                    ${employees}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
}
```

The problem here is that the button to show the sub-table is clicked and the `format` function is being executed and preparing the data as expected, but the sub-table is never shown the  `tr.addClass('shown');` is not working, and no error is shown in the console.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Where is `.button-subtable` in your html?If you debug your js,can you get the correct tr element with`var tr = $(this).closest('tr');`?

Comment: I've tried $(this).closest('tr').addClass('shown'); and it's the same, debugging I can see that the shown class is added apparently but I don't see the subtable displayed

Answer (score 0):

use `tr.classlist.add(class)` instead

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Comment: the .classlist is not a property of tr, is throwing the following console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')